# How to make a clickable link in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I am developing an iphone app right now where i will be displaying an overview text with entries that can be found later in the app.  I am wondering if there is a way to make a specific work clickable to send me to another screen that will display more information about the place that was clicked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this...

```
self.myTextView.dataDetectorTypes =UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Comment: so that will detect all links but what is the code to link to another iphone screen. Like what is the link reference to my activity.xib from my mainscreen.xib?

Comment: For that you have use UINavigation Controller. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @user618541, i guess he probably wants to know how to detect the link press?! @mrbaker, once you can detect the links, navigation to other screens are possible by pushing new view controllers (when using navigation controller) or presenting new view controller.

Comment: yeah I get how to use the UINavigaitonController but I don't think that will exactly do what I am talking about.  Like if I wanted to reference to a website I would just type the address and that would link to it but is there a way to type like Activity 1 and it will send me to the full description page for Activity 1 within my app?

Comment: @mrbaker, i can think of two scenario's. First, showing the activities as a list in table view, selecting would take to detailed view controller. Second, make use of UIWebView (use HTML formatting to show your data), which also lets you detect links, and can catch the events on links. For more information, refer to UIWebView and UIWebViewDelegateProtocol class references.

Answer (score 0):

if you want active substring in your UITextView then you can use my extended TextView... its short and simple. You can edit it as you want.

how to use (range = substring location):

```
[self.textView addTapActionWithRange:range withActionBlock:^{
      // anything you want to do - show something
}];
```

result: [image]

source code: https://github.com/marekmand/ActiveSubstringTextView